# Extended Kaddish for a Non-Shomer Shabbos Jew

Tags: mourning-aveilus, kaddish, secular-culture

[This website](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/c/5467/death_and_mourning?view=halachot) says that if one is saying Kaddish for someone who was not shomer Shabbos, one should continue to say Kaddish for 12 months instead of 11. What is the source for this practice?

Comment: What about the other way: why for a yes Shomer Shabbos Jew should you cut off a month to only 11?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the twelve months for someone who is not shomer shabbat is because the maximum time for a rasha is 12 months. That is, someone who deliberately refuses to keep shabbos or deliberately refuses to keep the halachos of kashrus would be considered a rasha in this sense. As we see [Kaddish Eleven or Twelve Months](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/236/Q3/)

> The Talmudic Sages teach that the maximum that a very wicked person
>   is punished in the afterlife in gehinom is 12 months. The public
>   recitation of kaddish shields the departed soul from this punishment.
>   Hence, kaddish is recited during the first year after a parent's
>   passing.
>
> However, the custom is to recite kaddish for 11 months only. Saying
>   kaddish the entire 12 months would give the impression that the
>   deceased was a very wicked person who needs protection the entire 12
>   months.
>
> So, unless the parent specifically requested it, or unless it's known
>   that the parent was a willful transgressor, kaddish is said for only
>   11 months.
>
> Sources:
>
> ```
> Gesher HaChaim
> P'nei Baruch
> ```

Comment: This helps with some bckgrou, information for the question but doesn't answer the question fully as this dies not give a source that kaddish is said for 12 months bc the meis did not keep shabbos

Comment: @Laser123 The point is that the meis is considered a rasha for deliberately not keeping shabbos.

Comment: @sabbahillel From where do we learn that one who deliberately violates shabbos is counted as a rasha?

Comment: @Ze'ev and beyond that: I don't think we consider most people to violate Shabbos "deliberately"

Comment: I seem to remember learning that you should always judge a person on the side of righteousness. Maybe the niftar made teshuvah before leaving this world. So in all cases Kaddish is said for 11 months.

Comment: @Epicentre Dan lekav zechus would determine if one would consider a person a rasha or not. The question was *given that the person is to have kaddish said for 12 months*, what is the rationale.